Normality of residuals in multinomial regression fitted with svyVGAM package
I would appreciate any help on how to test the normality of residuals in multinomial regression fitted with svyVGAM package.
Here is a workable example:
library(svyVGAM)

data(nhanes_sxq)

nhdes = svydesign(id = ~ SDMVPSU, strat = ~ SDMVSTRA, weights = ~ WTINT2YR,
                  nest = TRUE, data = nhanes_sxq)


mult_eth<- svy_vglm(RIDRETH1 ~ RIDAGEYR + DMDEDUC,
                    family = multinomial(refLevel = 3), design = nhdes)

summary(mult_eth)


https://www.statology.org/test-for-normality-in-r/
